# Specifying the agent name when starting a JadeGateway Agent

Tags: java, web-services, agents-jade

I am trying to do a jade Gateway prog. All is working fine. Except that now i need to have a way of specifying the local name of the Gateway Agent.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Assuming you start your Jade agent from the command line, what about the option `-agents GW:gateway-agent-class` of `jade.Boot` (assuming you want to name your agent "GW")
2. If creating an instance of JadeGateway class or Agent class, you name the agent when calling `createNewAgent()` for an `AgentContainer` instance.
3. If you use JadeGateway.init() then you only initialize the agent. According to FIPA an INITIALIZED agent has no name. Agent must reach at last ACTIVE state to have a name.
4. Unfortunately, according to [JadeGateway doc](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/api/jade/wrapper/gateway/JadeGateway.html): "The activation/termination of this agent (and its underlying container) are completely managed by the JadeGateway class and developers do not need to care about them". So no way to name a JadeGateway? Hm... it is a singleton, anyway.

Comment: I'm using this command to start my agent : JadeGateway.init("myPackage.myClassName",null);

Comment: Extended my answer. I start to believe it is not possible to assign a `local name` to a GW agent.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but it may help to other people. I haven´t found the way to change the JadeGateway agente name, but the container name can be set using the Profile.CONTAINER_NAME property. It will set the container name, and the Gateway agent created will be named "Control". In that way you can know what name will be assigned to the JadeGateway agent.